# Peg jump puzzle in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

Hi,everyone, I faced a question about solving the peg jump puzzle using python, and have searched from Google, but nothing is useful. 
There are a variety of puzzles that involve pegs in a board with a pattern of holes . The puzzle board is a line of regularly spaced holes. The number of holes can vary. The puzzle starts with some of the holes occupied by pegs, and some holes empty. The player proceeds by a series of jumps. In a jump, a peg moves over an [nearest] peg into an empty hole. The peg which was jumped over is removed. The goal of the puzzle is to find a sequence of jumps so that the board ends up with a single peg and all other holes empty.
For this project, the game board’s starting position is given as a Python string like so:

XoXoooXXoo

where X indicates a peg and o indicates an empty hole. An example of a valid jump would take this:

XooXX

to this:

XoXoo

where the rightmost peg has jumped to the left, removing the second from last peg.

The goal is to write a Python function pegsSolution(gameBoard) which returns a sequence of jumps that results in a board with a single peg. The sequence of jumps should be a Python list like so:

[ (3, ’L’), (5, ’R’), (4, ’L’) ]，the above example solution can be [(4,'L'),(0,'R')], result is oooox.

where each item in the list is a pair indicating the position of the peg which is jumping (counting from 0 on the left of the board) and the direction (either L or R for left or right). If there is no sequence of jumps which wins the game, then your function should return None.

Any advice and help will be appreciated, thanks .

Comment: How does `XooXX` get solved with `[(4,'L'),(0,'R')]`? I understand the first jump leads to `XoXoo`, but I don't see how any move is now possible, as there are no neighboring pegs anymore. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry , the  'adjacent  peg' is the  'nearest  peg',I have reedited  it .

Comment: So, if I have `oXoooXooXo` are `(5,'L')` and `(5,'R')` both valid moves?

Comment: Both invalid moves.

Comment: Then you lost me. I don't understand the rules.

Answer (score 1):

> I faced a question about solving the peg jump puzzle using python, and have searched from Google, but nothing is useful.

There is a complete, worked out solution with comments at:

```
https://github.com/macfreek/puzzle-code/blob/master/puzzle.py
```

The triangle peg puzzle is modeled as follows:

```
class TriPuzzle:

    pos = '011111111111111'

    goal = '100000000000000'

    triples = [[0,1,3], [1,3,6], [3,6,10], [2,4,7], [4,7,11], [5,8,12],
               [10,11,12], [11,12,13], [12,13,14], [6,7,8], [7,8,9], [3,4,5],
               [0,2,5], [2,5,9], [5,9,14], [1,4,8], [4,8,13], [3,7,12]]

    def __init__(self, pos = None):
        if pos: self.pos = pos

    def produce( self, t, sub ):
        return self.pos[:t[0]] + sub[0] + self.pos[t[0]+1:t[1]] + sub[1] + self.pos[t[1]+1:t[2]] + sub[2] + self.pos[t[2]+1:]

    def __iter__( self ):
        for t in self.triples:
            if self.pos[t[0]]=='1' and self.pos[t[1]]=='1' and self.pos[t[2]]=='0':
                yield self.__class__(self.produce(t,'001'))
            if self.pos[t[0]]=='0' and self.pos[t[1]]=='1' and self.pos[t[2]]=='1':
                yield self.__class__(self.produce(t,'100'))

    def __str__( self ):
        return '        %s\n      %s   %s\n    %s   %s   %s\n  %s   %s   %s   %s\n%s   %s   %s   %s   %s\n' % tuple(self.pos)
```

The default starting position is with an open peg at the top:

```
>> start_pos = TriPuzzle()
>>> print(start_pos)
        0
      1   1
    1   1   1
  1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
```

The most interesting method is `__iter__` which generates all possible moves from the current position:

```
>>> for next_pos in start_pos:
...     print(next_pos)

    
        1
      0   1
    0   1   1
  1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1

        1
      1   0
    1   1   0
  1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
```

The rest of the *Puzzle* class implemented a simple searcher that explores moves until the desired solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by implementing the following functions to define the rules of the game:

```
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple

Move = Tuple[int, str]  # e.g. (4, 'L') to jump board[4] to the left

def possible_moves(board: str) -> List[Move]:
    """Return all possible moves given a board position."""
    raise NotImplementedError

def apply_move(board: str, move: Move) -> str:
    """Apply given Move to the board and return the new board."""
    raise NotImplementedError

def is_winning_board(board) -> bool:
    """Defines whether a given board has reached the win condition."""
    return board.count("X") == 1

# Some simple unit tests
assert possible_moves("XooXX") == [(4, 'L')]
assert apply_move("XooXX", (4, 'L')) == "XoXoo"
assert not is_winning_board("XoXoo")
```

Once you have those helper functions it should be easy to write a recursive DFS to find the solution, something like:

```
def pegs_solution(board: str) -> Optional[List[Move]]:
    """Return a list of moves that results in a board with a single peg."""
    if is_winning_board(board):
        return []  # win condition
    for move in possible_moves(board):
        solution = pegs_solution(apply_move(board, move))
        if solution is not None:
            return [move] + solution
    return None  # lose condition
```

Comment: Thank you for your  advice , now I need  to  study DFS .